# PHP admin permission without login

Tags: php, admin

Is it okay if i do this to check if visitor is an admin adminpanel.php

```
$myip = "xxx.xxx.xxx"
$visitor_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if ($visitor_ip !== $myip) {
   header('index.php?noAdminPermission')
}else {
 //do normal stuff

}
```

Comment: You need to `exit`, `die`, or otherwise stop execution after the `header` call.

Comment: I would use vhost/htaccess for this

Comment: Since you decided to check the admin by their IP, I suggest you stop closing the door to your apartment and just put a chair in the doorway instead. Hopefully nobody enters.

Answer (score 2):

No. But you're close.

Your missing `Location:` in the `header()` function, and missing `exit()` to stop the script.

Additionally, you should test the presence of `REMOTE_ADDR` in the array `$_SERVER`.

Finally, the `else` statement is no longer required.

It should be :

```
$myip = "xxx.xxx.xxx"
$visitor_ip = isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] : '' ;
if ($visitor_ip !== $myip) {
   header('Location: index.php?noAdminPermission');
   exit(0);
}
//do normal stuff
```

Comment: @Sejoo You're welcome :) I've updated the anwser with the most informations as possible.